# Function iterates through array of object and flatten selected object properties as string

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am trying to write a custom function that iterates through an array of objects, and flatten any chosen object property keys by return them as a string joined by comma.

Probably better explain by code:

```
var products = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "variants": {
      "colour": "black"
    },
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "variants": {
      "colour": "red"
    }
  }
];

function joinedByComma(arr, keys) {
  // some code
}

joinedByComma(products, ["variants", "colour" ]);
// returns "black,red"
```

Any insights on how to write the function `joinedByComma`? The number of items in the second array parameter can be any length depending on how nested the object is...

Comment: Did you try anything ? What's exactly the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const joinedByComma = (arr, keys) =>
   arr.map(el => keys.reduce((obj, key) => obj[key] || {}, el)).join();
```

Just map the array to each entry by reducing the keys to the value of the object, then just join them.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the insights. I will attempt to expand the code to include other edge cases too e.g if the nested property is another array than object